# nested data binding of Observable collection in xaml

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am creating a WPF application which takes a file as input and draw graphs for different objects which are in the file.

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" 
                    Height= "600" Width="Auto">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BiggerCollection}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas x:Name="front_canvas" Background="White" Height="1200" Width="{Binding CanvasWidth}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Line X1="{Binding From.X}" Y1="{Binding From.Y}"
                                    X2="{Binding To.X}" Y2="{Binding To.Y}"
                                    Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

The property "Lines" is a collection of CustomLineViewModel. In CustomLineViewModel, there are two properties named "From" and "To". Both are of data type Point. I am not able to see anything on the screen. Backend logic is fine because during debugging i have checked the values of different variables.

Comment: Have you checked your output screen to see if you have any binding errors?

Comment: sorry could not understand. which output screen are you talking about.?

Comment: The one in visual studio, as a last resort, just create a dummy constructor that only has a Debugger.Break() and use that to confirm what is the value of your items at runtime.

Comment: Set breakpoints and make sure that BiggerCollection is being read, what state it's in when it is read and so on. But as @mahlatse pointed out, read the Output window VS -> View -> Output as it shows up binding errors.